# Finiteness of a bilinear combination

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities

For $j\in\mathbb{N}$, consider continuous functions $f_j:[0,1]\to\mathbb{\mathbb{R}^+}$ such that
$$\sup_{t\in[0,1]}\sum_jf_j(t)<+\infty,$$
namely $f_j(t)\in L_t^{\infty}((0,1),l_j^1(\mathbb{N}))$. I would like to understand whether the quantity
$$S_f:=\sum_{j,k\in\mathbb{N}}\int_0^1f_j(t)f_k(t)dt$$
is finite. Some observations:

- If for every $j$ the function $f_j$ is increasing in $t$, then $S_f$ is finite. Indeed,

$$S_f\leq \sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}f_j(T)\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\int_0^1 f_k(t)dt\leq \sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}f_j(T)\int_0^1\sup_{t\in[0,1]}\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}f_k(t)dt<+\infty$$

Similarly, if the functions $f_j$ attains their maxima on a finite set of points in $[0,1]$, then $S_f$ is finite.

- More generally, $S_f$ is finite if $f_j(t)\in L_j^1L_t^{\infty}$, but of course this is not always the case. For example, one can take (a smooth modification of) $f_j(t):=\delta_{t=j^{-1}}$. Nevertheless, also in this case $S_f$ is finite.
- I tried to consider the case when the $f_j$ have plenty of oscillations, but I was unable to find a counterexample.

So my question is the following: **is it true that $S_f$ is always finite?**

In the context I'm interested, there is an additional (weak) control of the derivatives of $f_j$, of the form $2^{-j}f_j'\in L^1(0,1)$, so one could also try to prove the finiteness of $S_f$ under this additional assumption.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. Indeed,
$$M:=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}\sum_jf_j(t)<\infty,$$
and hence
$$\begin{aligned}S_f&=\sum_{j,k\in\mathbb{N}}\int_0^1f_j(t)f_k(t)\,dt \\ 
&=\int_0^1\sum_{j,k\in\mathbb{N}}f_j(t)f_k(t)\,dt \\
&=\int_0^1\Big(\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}f_j(t)\Big)^2\,dt \\ 
&\le\int_0^1 M^2\,dt=M^2<\infty,
\end{aligned}$$
as desired.